# PowerBI - Replace Zeros with Blanks

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI Report showing columns of figures representing hours of support we've sold by customer. Those figures are calculated in PowerBI by men.

But some customers haven't bought any support - so I want to show those columns for those customers as blank, not zero.

I can do this easily by turning the whole column to text, rather than numeric, and the blank fields can just be "". But users want to be able to export the visual and have the numbers be numbers (not text) when it gets to Excel.

Is there any way I can have 0 values show as blank in this case?

Comment: Are you talking about in the query editor (M code) or afterward in your data model (DAX)?

Comment: "...calculated by **men**? *Mean* perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you've set up your data and what you'd really like to do with it. But until we get some clarifications here's is my take on it:

---

Some sample data:

```
Hours,Customer
1,AA
2,BB
2,CC
0,DD
4,EE
```

If you import that data using `Get Data` and activate the `Power Query Editor`, you can right-click `Hours`, select `Replace Values` and replace `0` with *`null`* to get this:

[image]

Click `Close&Apply` to get back to the desktop and select a `Clustered Column Chart`. Assign `Customer` to `Axis` and `Hours` to `Values` so that you get this:

[image]

As you can see, `DD` is not there, which I believe is how you'd like to *illustrate* your data. But now you can also click `Customer` under `VISUALIZATIONS > Axis` and select 
`Show items with no data`:

[image]

And you'll get this:

[image]

If you now select `Export Data` [image] you'll get a txt file with all the customers, but with no data for customer `DD` that originally had the value `0`:

[image]

Please let me know if this is not what you were looking for.