# Replace (Blank) values in PowerBI with Zero

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to set up a Hospitalization Dashboard within PowerBI and I'm using the KPI indicator to showcase the number of patients in that particular location.

My Source Data looks as follows:

```
Full Name | ID | Location
Patient A | xxxxxA | ITU
Patient B | xxxxxA | IDU
```

Then I generate a KPI indicator that if is Count of Location and filtered for anything that contains 'ITU'. At times, this generates a '(BLANK)' value in the indicator and I would like to know how to replace this with zero. Somehow can't figure out where to get started, if to do a measure etc.

The following questions somehow didn't help:

[PowerBI - Replace Zeros with Blanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527341/powerbi-replace-zeros-with-blanks)

[PowerBI Differentiate BLANK value and 0 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756571/powerbi-differentiate-blank-value-and-0-value)

[Replacing Blank values with Zero using Dax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406040/replacing-blank-values-with-zero-using-dax)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your KPI measure is numeric, then you can usually just add `+ 0` to the measure since

```
BLANK() + 0 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis for this. Where should I put this measure exactly?

Comment: Same place as your existing measure? It's just a small modification to the measure rather than an entirely new one.

Comment: Thank you! Finally solved it :) Appreciate your help