# Replace blanks with zero in a matrix table in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am using a power BI matrix report and I want to fill the blank values to 0 in the matrix tables. The data source would be a table from SQL server.

I am looking for options to fill the blank values with 0 using power BI? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no option for that. also BLANK is more meaningful for Matrix as 0 represents a value where as Blank means there is nothing for the column and row combination.

Comment: Does this question or any of the ones it links to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103698/replace-blank-values-in-powerbi-with-zero

Answer (score -1):

In a given table, (Blank) often comes from "null" in a column. Under Transform data, you can select the column you want to edit, then select "Replace Values" in the Home ribbon. Then it just works like a find and replace in any editor.

As mentioned in the comments, Blank is there for a reason and replacing to 0 may be a bad idea, depending on the data. In general, I try not to destroy any data unless entirely unavoidable.

Consider other solutions:

Like if you just don't want your calculated visualizations to show "(Blank)", do something like `Measure = CALCULATE(<something>)+0` and it'll show a calculation of 0 if theres nothing in the column.

If you have a slicer showing a "(Blank)" category, just filter it out in the filters sidebar.

Comment: The question is specific for a Power BI Matrix visual. Is this going to work with that as well?

Comment: Ya.. I have the same question as well? Since I see the matrix table is already calculated and I see how can I recalculate it  using Measure = CALCULATE(<something>)+0?

Comment: @Aarthy I don't know what your application is specifically, so take it with a grain of salt, but...

If you wanted to count a number of customer records in a matrix and your x, y were some details about customer records, but not all (x, y) value pairs would yield a non-null value in the matrix, then you could certainly write a measure `#records = count(table[column])+0`, which would yield a 0 instead of an empty space or the word "(Blank)". You could, of course, also put calculate() around it if you wanted filters on count.

Maybe you could give more context about your particular dataset?